# Error connecting to database: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type

Tags: buildmaster

I am trying to register new database in my application and here are my connection strings but none of them working and throwing error after upgrading version from 4.1.7 to 4.2.1

```
Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;
Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;
Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;ProviderName=System.Data.SqlClient


Error connecting to database: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in BuildMaster 4.2.1 (#BM-1448); it impacts primarily the web application, but it should still work OK in the service. It will be fixed in the next maintennce release, which is due later today.